# Filter "My Tags" questions using "Interesting Tags"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, unanswered-questions

It's confusing to me that the "My Tags" tab of the Unanswered questions page doesn't use my "Interesting Tags". Instead, it appears to use the 25 most overall popular tags that were on any question I ever answered. The current implementation doesn't end up displaying the unanswered questions that actually match my interests.

Answer (score 11):

Actually if we could add the `Interesting Tags` filter to each major section (front page, Questions, and Unanswered) that would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

Any better use of "Interesting Tags" would be an improvement; either filtering in "My Tags", or having a checkable filter for any display.   This was a popular request on uservoice.