# Why is the non-required tag displayed as the first tag of the question?

Tags: support, specific-question, sorting, required-tags

In general, for all questions one of the [required tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/required-tags) is displayed as the first tag. But for this [community wiki question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1187/312043), a moderator-only-tag is displayed as the first tag and the required tag is displayed in the last position.

Is this a bug or any feature for the wiki question?

**Screenshots for reference:**

**In the Home page:**
[image: In the Home page]

**In the question page:**
[image: In the question page]

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1066/295232) is another recent example (snapshots: [Q&A page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507111214/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/add-support-for-abbr-tag), [homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/20211202115958/https://meta.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *guess* this has something to do with the MSO → MSE migration.

The earliest snapshot I could find in the Wayback Machine is from [July 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090703094405/http://meta.stackoverflow.com:80/questions/1187/filter-my-tags-questions-using-interesting-tags):

[image]

when it was tagged (in that order) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions) [from-uservoice](/questions/tagged/from-uservoice).

The earliest snapshot on Meta Stack Exchange is [from September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911032007/http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/filter-my-tags-questions-using-interesting-tags)

[image]

when the tags are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Migration can do [strange things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340503/4751173) to tag order, and I think this is no exception. When <s>I</s> my script edited the question earlier today, it did not change the tags, so they're left in their original order. If somebody edits those, I guess they'll end up in the correct order again.

Comment: Just tried making a tag edit, and it looks like you’re right, they’re now in the correct order.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist and rolling back doesn't restore the original order, it seems...